# jackson: mapping enum to different values?

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

I have an service that talks to backend servers and front-end clients. The backend apps are expecting JSON in one format and the front-end apps are expecting it in a different format.  The enums from the backend servers are different than what the front-end clients are expecting.

For example the backend is expecting:

```
public enum BlogPubState { NONE, PUBLISHED }
```

While the front-end is expecting:

```
public enum BlogPubState { UNPUBLISHED, PUBLISHED }
```

Is there away to setup jackson to change NONE to UNPUBLISHED when it deserializes incoming JSON?

Edit:

Also in case it helps.  I really need a solution that involves enums.  This is because we have one model but need to use different JSON for the backend and front-end.

Thanks!